# Atom Shell Commands

Tags: shell, atom-editor

I had previously installed the shell commands so I could be able to open atom from my terminal. However, I tried using it today and it didn't work: "atom: command not found". I proceeded to install the commands again, and everything worked fine. By then I decided to reboot the computer and open terminal again, and open a file using the atom command, and once again: "atom: command not found".

I don't think I should install the shell commands every time I try to use the terminal right? How can I fix this?

Comment: You may want to raise an issue on the atom github issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks! found a solution there

Comment: You're welcome.  I've added this as an answer, would appreciate it if you would mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  I found a solution after some searching.

In your terminal;

run:

`which atom`

should return:
/usr/local/bin/atom

In atom;

Hold: 

`Cmd+Shift+P`

then when you get a text box, run:

`Window: Install Shell Commands`

It confirms and then you're good to go.
https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/